# How to Keep Theme selected by User even if page reloads?

Tags: angular, themes, angular-material

I am working on theming of my angular app. When User click a button to change the theme , the theme is getting changed successfully. 
But once the page is refreshed the selected theme is getting lost and the default theme is loading. 
Is there anyway to maintain the theme chosen by user even if the browser is refreshed( or till logout or a particular period of time). 
I have googled it but not able to find any effective solution. 
I am thinking of maintaining the theme settings in cookies. Can Anyone  please guide me on this ?

theme.scss file :

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// Typography
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: Raleway,
  $headline: mat-typography-level(24px, 48px, 400),
  $body-1: mat-typography-level(16px, 24px, 400)
);
@include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);

// Default colors
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-teal, 700, 100, 800);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-teal, 700, 100, 800);

$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent);
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);

// Dark theme
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

.dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}

// Light theme
$light-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 200, 500, 300);
$light-accent: mat-palette($mat-brown, 200);
$light-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, 200);

$light-theme: mat-light-theme($light-primary, $light-accent, $light-warn);

.light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($light-theme)
}
```

component.html file :

```html
<mat-slide-toggle class="ctheme" (click)="toggleTheme()">Change Theme!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

```js
toggleTheme() {
    if (this.isdarkTheme) {
       this.theme = 'default-theme';
    } else {
        this.theme = 'dark-theme';
    }
    this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(this.theme);
    this.componentCssClass = this.theme;
    this.isdarkTheme = !this.isdarkTheme;
    }
```

Comment: Put the theming into a service, and on `window:unload` store the theme in local storage. And on `ngOnInit` of your app, get the theme from local storage and load it up if one exists.

Comment: @JunKang Do you know how we can retrieve current applied theme name?

Comment: That entirely depends specifically on how you're doing it. Show your code, html and ts.

Comment: @JunKang I have added details.

Comment: Yeah, we don't care about the scss file. But your theme name is literally right there. `this.theme = 'whatever-theme';` You don't even need to set `'default-theme'` there. If there is no theme applied, it'll automatically be your 'default-theme'.

Comment: on this page it will fine. What if i am on some different page where this.theme is not accessible ?

Comment: Like I said already, wrap your themeing code into a service, and use the service injected in whatever components you want.

Comment: Oh.. ok I will work around this solution.. thanks @junKang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Wrap your theming code into a sharable service. Something along these lines. Make sure you provide the service in `app.module.ts`.

```
@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {
  constructor() {}

  private _selectedTheme = "";

  get selectedTheme() {
    return this._selectedTheme;
  }

  setSelectedTheme(theme: string) {
    this._selectedTheme = theme;
  }

  setThemeToDefault() {
    this._selectedTheme = "";
  }
}
```

Step 2: Inject theme service into whatever components you want so you can get/save your selected theme. 
Step 3: Inject theme service into main `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private themeService: ThemeService) { }
}
```

Step 4: Use `@HostListener` to listen for unload event to store current selected theme in local storage if one exists. Make sure you `import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event) {
  if (this.themeService.selectedTheme) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("selectedTheme", this.themeService.selectedTheme);
  }
}
```

Step 5: In your main `app.component.ts`, set your theme if one exists in local storage.

```
ngOnInit() {
  var theme = window.localStorage.getItem("selectedTheme");
  if (theme) {
    this.themeService.setSelectedTheme(theme);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JunKang . There is no need to create separate theme service for the same. After a long work around finally i am able to achieve it.